# Rails Load Class With Unconventional Folder Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I have a module I want to call OAuth and a class inside it called AccessToken.  Normally in rails I would want to put it in `app/models/o_auth/access_token.rb`.  How can I get it to load from the path `app/models/oauth/access_token.rb`?

Comment: Anything inside `app` folder will load automatically

Comment: Sort of.  Rails checks if OAuth is loaded, and when it finds that it isnt, it looks for the folder o_auth, which isn't what I'm calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question was too subtle.  I was asking how to load my class from that specific path, not how to add a path to the autoload path in general.  My issue was that because my OAuth class starts with two capital letters, rails expects a path of o_auth as does anything where you might reference it as a symbol.  Because of all the overriding you would have to do to get symbol references of oauth to point to an OAuth class, it seems it is better to just name the folder o_auth instead of oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `require 'app/models/o_auth/access_token'` at the top of `application.rb`, and at the top of any other model that uses it. This is what you'd have to do for every model, without RoR's "convention over configuration" ideal, and its magic importer.

Comment: i guess require 'app/models/oauth/access_token' would get me the result I'm wanting?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `config/application.rb`

```ruby
# Load Subfolder Models
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```